# what do I need to do to fix my cakephp routes

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

currently when I click a link in on my website it is creating a url that looks like this

```
http://domainname.com/app/webroot/index.php/links
```

this causes the page to load incorrectly. if I edit the url by hand to look like this

```
http://domainname.com/links
```

everything loads correctly. My three .htaccess files look like this
/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteBase / 
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L] 
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L] 

</IfModule>
```

app/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L] 
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L] 
 </IfModule>
```

app/webroot/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```

is there something I need to change in here? am I supposed to make these changes somewhere else?  This site is hosted on godaddy's shared hosting. I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

UPDATE:
here is the link.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Portfolio', array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'index'))?>
```

I've also tried removing the `RewriteBase /` line from all of the files.  That didn't help.

also this is what is in my routes.php file.

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: The problem is probably in the link, not in the .htaccess - can you show what the link looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to comment out the following line in the core.php file.

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

I forgot that I had to uncomment it to get things working on my development server.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out all the RewriteBase lines

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can check:

1. mod_rewrite is available and working
2. Apache config allows
   these options: Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
3. RewriteBase in
   your .htaccess actually rewrites to the correct dir if you have
   multiple cakephp apps. E.g. I have to use RewriteBase
   /~shaz/webapps/myapp/

Also there's loads of posts on google and even on stackoverflow so it might be worth ensuring you have the same "default" settings / environment as someone else, and working your way from there.

If all else fails, you can use the alternative "pretty" url setting provided in the config/core.php file.